# How to compare number with string by -gt in shell programming

Tags: linux, shell

I don't know if exist a var `$b` ,make the value of the expression :

```
[[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]] && [[ "$b" -gt 88888888 ]]
```

is true?...

Answer (score 0):

It's not terribly well documented (IIRC), but `-gt` (and the other integer comparison operators) forces the comparison to be made in an arithmetic context, which means an empty value of `$b` is treated the same as 0.

```
$ [[ 3 -gt $undefined ]] && echo true
true
$ [[ -3 -lt $undefined ]] && echo true
true
$ [[ 0 -eq $undefined ]] && echo true
true
```

This is more clearly seen using the fact that strings are recursively expanded as variables until an integer is found as well:

```
$ foo=bar
$ bar=3
$ [[ 3 -eq bar ]] && echo true
true
$ [[ 3 == bar ]] || echo false
false
```